# Check length of commit message

Tags: git, hook, git-commit

I have a `git` hook which should prevent commit messages that have more than 72 characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Hook to make sure that no commit message line exceeds 72 characters

while read line; do
    if [ ${#line} -ge 72 ]; then
        echo "Commit messages are limited to 72 characters."
        echo "The following commit message has ${#line} characters."
        echo "${line}"
        exit 1
    fi
done < "${1}"

exit 0
```

This was working fine until now. I tried to rebase a commit and change its commit message, and then `git` would rightfully tell me:

```
Commit messages are limited to 72 characters.
The following commit message has 81 characters.
# You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '984734a'.
Could not amend commit after successfully picking 19b8030dc0ad2fc8186df5159b91e0efe862b981... Fill SUSY decay dictionary on the fly when needed
This is most likely due to an empty commit message, or the pre-commit hook
failed. If the pre-commit hook failed, you may need to resolve the issue before
you are able to reword the commit.
```

The method I use is not very smart. How would I do this properly?

Comment: What do you want to do? limit all messages to 72? support longer on merge? Please be more accurate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply skipping comments (lines starting with `#` did the trick):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Hook to make sure that no commit message line exceeds 72 characters

while read line; do
    # Skip comments
    if [ "${line:0:1}" == "#" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    if [ ${#line} -ge 72 ]; then
        echo "Commit messages are limited to 72 characters."
        echo "The following commit message has ${#line} characters."
        echo "${line}"
        exit 1
    fi
done < "${1}"

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script copied from [this post](http://addamhardy.com/2013/06/05/good-commit-messages-and-enforcing-them-with-git-hooks.html):

> #### What I want this script to do:
>
> - Verify I have a summary line on my commit
> - Verify the summary line is not over 50 characters
> - Verify no line is over 72 characters
> - If there are any errors, reject my commit and ask me to reformat
> - If I choose to reformat my commit, bring me back into the commit editor and - show me what exactly was wrong with my commit in comments on the commit message

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os
from subprocess import call

print os.environ.get('EDITOR')

if os.environ.get('EDITOR') != 'none':
  editor = os.environ['EDITOR']
else:
  editor = "vim"

message_file = sys.argv[1]

def check_format_rules(lineno, line):
    real_lineno = lineno + 1
    if lineno == 0:
        if len(line) > 50:
            return "Error %d: First line should be less than 50 characters " \
                    "in length." % (real_lineno,)
    if lineno == 1:
        if line:
            return "Error %d: Second line should be empty." % (real_lineno,)
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        if len(line) > 72:
            return "Error %d: No line should be over 72 characters long." % (
                    real_lineno,)
    return False


while True:
    commit_msg = list()
    errors = list()
    with open(message_file) as commit_fd:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(commit_fd):
            stripped_line = line.strip()
            commit_msg.append(line)
            e = check_format_rules(lineno, stripped_line)
            if e:
                errors.append(e)
    if errors:
        with open(message_file, 'w') as commit_fd:
            commit_fd.write('%s\n' % '# GIT COMMIT MESSAGE FORMAT ERRORS:')
            for error in errors:
                commit_fd.write('#    %s\n' % (error,))
            for line in commit_msg:
                commit_fd.write(line)
        re_edit = raw_input('Invalid git commit message format.  Press y to edit and n to cancel the commit. [y/n]')
        if re_edit.lower() in ('n','no'):
            sys.exit(1)
        call('%s %s' % (editor, message_file), shell=True)
        continue
    break
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. When I try to commit something, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/hooks/commit-msg", line 48, in <module>
    re_edit = raw_input('Invalid git commit message format.  Press y to edit and n to cancel the commit. [y/n]')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line`